# Facebook Login get cors when closing login popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I get error when Im trying login to my facebook
When my login popup, after continue with my Account, if I click "Close", I will get this error "block by cors":

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://www.facebook.com/x/oauth/status?ancestor_origins=https%3A%2F%2FmyProjectLink.net&client_id=1074143986372695&input_token&origin=1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FmyProject2.net%2Fversion&sdk=joey&wants_cookie_data=true'
> from origin 'https://myProject2Link.net' has been blocked by
> CORS policy

here is my code setup

```
              <Button
                className="ui-button ui-button--destroy btn-primary btn-next-version"
                onClick={this.handleSaveKeywordManual}
              >
                Continue
              </Button>
...
  handleSaveKeywordManual(e) {
    
    $(".circle6_optimal").css("display","block");
    $(".container").addClass("opacity-loading");
    var paramFbLogin = DiagnoseService.getUrlParameter2("fb_login");
    if(paramFbLogin == false || paramFbLogin == "false"){
      VersionService.saveConfig($('input[name="rdo_version2"]:checked').val(),"757372958322188","123","1076750259412980","EAAJmvZBtQgWMBAIdVJAOEPBHSYFQ4LKPg6HydCrhYM9Q9iK836WOKHEHwNp2Mqd4OBBFnLgOE3suO6DZB5t5YZCxyRNPYepOqASXZBSxJZBcZCpJRtxZBj3G49AnLasQ4quW5N9yiCoisnfGKeXNIQHhZAxQ0cGW2ZBC12DKzwmDI4AZDZD", "150874148894921");
      sessionStorage.setItem("access_token","EAAJmvZBtQgWMBAIdVJAOEPBHSYFQ4LKPg6HydCrhYM9Q9iK836WOKHEHwNp2Mqd4OBBFnLgOE3suO6DZB5t5YZCxyRNPYepOqASXZBSxJZBcZCpJRtxZBj3G49AnLasQ4quW5N9yiCoisnfGKeXNIQHhZAxQ0cGW2ZBC12DKzwmDI4AZDZD");
    }
    else{
      launchFBE();  
    }
  }
```

And my setup script

```
  <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            //2. FB JavaScript SDK configuration and setup
            FB.init({
                appId: 'myFBAppID', // FB App ID
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
                version: 'v4.0' // uses graph api version v4.0
            });
        };

        //1. Load the JavaScript SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        //3. Facebook login with JavaScript SDK
        function launchFBE() {
            var m = new Date();
            var dateString = m.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + (m.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "-" + m.getUTCDate() + " " + m.getUTCHours() + ":" + m.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + m.getUTCSeconds();
            var dateNowConvert = new Date(dateString + "Z");
            var fb_bm_id = dateNowConvert.getTime();

            FB.login(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.authResponse) {

                    // returns a User Access Token with scopes requested
                    const accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    sessionStorage.setItem("access_token", accessToken);
                    var settings = {
                        "url": "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/fbe_business/fbe_installs?fbe_external_business_id=" + fb_bm_id + "&access_token=" + accessToken + "",
                        "method": "GET",
                        "timeout": 0,
                    };

                    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {

                        console.log(response);
                        if (response.data) {
                            if (response.data.length > 0) {
                                var ad_account = response.data[0].ad_account_id;
                                var business_manager_id = response.data[0].business_manager_id;
                                var business_manager_name = "";
                                var settingsGetBusinessName = {
                                    "url": "https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/" + business_manager_id + "?access_token=" + accessToken + "",
                                    "method": "GET",
                                    "timeout": 0,
                                    "async": false
                                };
                                $.ajax(settingsGetBusinessName).done(function(responseBusinessName) {
                                    business_manager_name = responseBusinessName.name;
                                });
                                var catalog_id = response.data[0].catalog_id;
                                var pixel_id = response.data[0].pixel_id;
                                var pages = response.data[0].pages[0];
                                var profiles = response.data[0].profiles[0];

                                sessionStorage.setItem("business_facebook_id", business_manager_id + "|" + business_manager_name);
                                sessionStorage.setItem("catalog_facebook_id", catalog_id);
                                sessionStorage.setItem("page_id", pages);
                                sessionStorage.setItem("pixel_id", pixel_id);

                                var settings = {
                                    "url": "https://myProject2Link/api/store/config",
                                    "method": "PUT",
                                    "timeout": 0,
                                    "headers": {
                                        "X-App-Facebook-Shop-Token": sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
                                        "X-App-StoreAlias": sessionStorage.getItem("alias"),
                                        "x-app-storeid": sessionStorage.getItem("storeId"),
                                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                                    },
                                    "data": JSON.stringify({
                                        "config": {
                                            "version": $('input[name="rdo_version2"]:checked').val(),
                                            "access_token_facebook": "" + accessToken + "",
                                            "business_facebook_id": "" + business_manager_id + "|" + business_manager_name + "",
                                            "pixel_facebook_id": "" + pixel_id + "",
                                            "catalog_facebook_id": "" + catalog_id + "",
                                            "page_id": "" + pages + "",
                                            "modified_on": m
                                        }
                                    }),
                                };

                                $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {

                                    sessionStorage.setItem("is_config", true);
                                    sessionStorage.removeItem("config_again");
                                    sessionStorage.setItem("version", $('input[name="rdo_version2"]:checked').val());

                                    $(".circle6_optimal").css("display", "none");
                                    $(".container").removeClass("opacity-loading");
                                    location.reload();
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    // store access token for later  
                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            }, {
                scope: 'catalog_management,manage_business_extension',
                // refer to the extras object table for details
                extras: {
                    "setup": {
                        "external_business_id": "" + fb_bm_id + "",
                        "timezone": "Asia/Saigon",
                        "currency": "VND",
                        "business_vertical": "ECOMMERCE"
                    },
                    "business_config": {
                        "business": {
                            "name": "ABC"
                        }
                    },
                    "repeat": false
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Tks for spending your time

Answer (score -1):

CORS is going to be on your backend.  Somewhere in your server side you'll have to allow Facebook in your CORS options.  Also check to make sure the callback URL on your app settings is the same as what you're pointing to in your code.

Comment: _“Somewhere in your server side you'll have to allow Facebook in your CORS options.”_ - that makes no sense whatsoever. The only party that _can_ allow cross-domain requests in this scenario here, is Facebook.